# new installation dropping me to login prompt. No GUI

Tags: 11.10, macbook, boot-failure

Just now i installed Ubuntu on my Mac and when i booted it after installation then it just gets stuck on Blue/purple screen. I rebooted and this time chose option of booting in recovery mode where i then selected 'normal boot' and then i was dropped at login command prompt. No GUI screen or anything. What can be done?

Comment: Has anybody experience this?? I don't think it is related to Mac

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with your graphics drivers.
Firstly, login to your installation through the prompt. Then run
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to update your installation.
This is a precautionary step. Just in case yours is a bug and it has been fixed, your problem will be solved straightaway.

Then, try starting the Xserver by using the command `startx`
If that works, then you have a working GUI now. Reboot and check if the GUI works properly. if not, some package (probably lightdm) is broken. in any case, posting the output/errors generated by `startx` should help in further diagnosis.
You may also consider filing a bug at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect)